# Fetching Data from one table and inserting into another using stored procedure in SQL 2012

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I want to fetch data from one table and insert into another using stored procedure.
Below is my code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uspInitiateSRFWorkFlow 
        @WFPolicyID nvarchar(50) = null 
    AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;    
        INSERT INTO ProjectWorkflowAgg
        SELECT * FROM WFPolicyDetails where MasterCode = @WFPolicyID ORDER BY Priority ASC;
    END
    GO
```

Error is :
Msg 2809, Level 18, State 1, Line 1
The request for procedure 'WFPolicyDetails' failed because 'WFPolicyDetails' is a table object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It better to specify Columns in insert and select statment..

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uspInitiateSRFWorkFlow 
        @WFPolicyID nvarchar(50) = null 
    AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;    
        INSERT INTO ProjectWorkflowAgg(Column1...,Column)
        SELECT Column1...,Column FROM WFPolicyDetails where MasterCode = @WFPolicyID ORDER BY Priority ASC;
    END
    GO
```

Comment: Lemme me check friend.

Answer (score 0):

To fetch the data from one table and enter it to another it is best to use a trigger. To learn how to use the triggers, here is the link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms189799.aspx.

Hopefully it may help with your problem. Best of luck!!